After I change the metadata URI and the name of a SPL token, when will the updated name be displayed in Phantom or Solflare wallet?
I updated name and URI of a SPL token. Updated name is displaying in solscan but still not showing in phantom or solflare wallet. Why?
Here the solscan link https://solscan.io/token/tWingCubHQqBMgKSa9HVCsdGH8Uq4NfKtRbEVsexD4N#metadata
Here is the tx of metadata URI update: https://solscan.io/tx/z3HWSKB2ZAQ2r9rEP9vBN2wKAYxANt2vybUrP7wrzEVkKkrD3Vfwbts89vYpVysnTjnbRhrdGVc66cuDKB68yzT
After that the name of token is not updated in phantom wallet but updated in solscan

If you look at https://explorer.solana.com/address/tWingCubHQqBMgKSa9HVCsdGH8Uq4NfKtRbEVsexD4N you'll see they detect your token as a duplicata. Probably why phantom is ignoring it
